# C++ copy constructor compilation error

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have read some articles concerning this topic but still have problems to compile my own code.

I have class A:

```
class A
{
public:
     List<int> data;  
     A(){} 
     A(A&){}
     A& operator= (const A& a)
     {
         // copy the data from a to data  
     }       
};
```

Class B will call class A:

```
class B
{
public:
    A makeA()
    {
        A a;
        return a;
    }
    A getA()
    {
        A a = makeA();
        return a;
    }
};
```

When I compile my code with g++ under Linux, I got:

no matching function for call to 'A::A(A)'.

It seems that the compiler has simply ignored the assignment operation. Can you help me out of this?

Comment: Try implementing your copy constructor `A(A&){}` properly: `A(const A &input){/*blah*/}

Comment: `A a = makeA()` is trying to call a copy constructor, rather than an assignment operator.  The compiler should make one for you, but your definition `A(A&){}` is suspect... you need `const A&` for this particular call since you're passing an rvalue.

Comment: Do you mean `#include <list>` followed by `std::list` rather than `List`?

Answer (score 3):

In order for this to compile, your copy constructor must take its parameter by `const` reference:

```
A(const A&){}
```

Adding `const` to your constructor signature fixes this problem ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/ZRbI0q)).

Since you are defining an assignment operator and a copy constructor, you should strongly consider adding a desctructor `~A()` (see the [*Rule of Three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)).

Comment: Thank you very much, I have also found this myself

Comment: Formally, a "copy constructor" can take `const A&`, `A&`, or `volatile A&`. In this example, as you say, only the `const A&` form can be used.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment operator is not used here.

```
A a = makeA();
```

This line is an initialization; it uses the copy constructor to copy the value returned by `makeA` into `a`. The compiler is complaining because `A::A(A&)` can't be used with a temporary; change it to the much more common form `A(const A&)` and things will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter is right.  The copy constructor `A(A&){}` wants to be `A(const A&){}`, instead.  The reason is that `A(A&){}` tells the compiler to prepare to modify the `A` passed to the copy constructor, which does not really make sense, and certainly does not make sense in case the `A` you pass is a temporary.